# Getting Data in and out of Rhipe [R + Hadoop]

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs, export-to-csv, rhadoop

I was trying out rhipe and RHadoop [rmr rhdfs rhbase etc.] series of packages.

Now in both of the packages [rhipe and rmr] I can ingest / read the data stored into csv or text file. Both of them kind of supports creation of new file formats but I find rmr has more support for it or at least more resources to get started. Well, this requirement will be useful when one plans to perform few data processing on raw data stored in HDFS and finally want to store it back to HDFS in a format recognizable by other components of Hadoop like Hive Impala etc. Both of the packages can write in their native format recognizable by the package only. The package rmr supports few other formats.

For reference related to rmr have a look into: https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rmr2/blob/master/docs/getting-data-in-and-out.md

However for rhipe I did not get any such document and I tried various ways it failed.

So my question is how can I write back into text [as for example, other recognizable format will also work] after reading a file stored into HDFS and running `rhwatch` in rhipe ?